# Подключение с серверу Mongo

Tags: mongodb

> Объясните, пожалуйста, почему у автора другой интерфейс(нижний)? Необходимо подключится к базе Mongo

[image: Мой интерфейс]
[image: Интерфейс автора]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может через cmd надо подключаться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to connect to the local one or the cloud one - Atlas? If its the local one, just use localost field and the one below it, with the default port.

If you need the Atlas one, go to the website, get a special code and change  and  to your user and password. User is not your login, you have to create a new user entity for your database in a tab "Database access" on a website.

When changing  you have to erase those < > things.

Интерфейс не другой, он такой же, просто нажми fill individual fields и у тебя выйдет такая же форма. На первом и втором скриншоте ты создаешь один и тот же адрес, просто там он в виде строчки, а тут в виде формы и компьютер сам за тебя эти поля соберет в точно такую же строчку.

Куда именно ты хочешь подключиться? К локальной базе на компе или к базе атлас в облаке? Если к локальной, то у тебя уже есть слева куча подключений, для него нужны только поля localhost и port которые уже за тебя заполнены.

Если к атласу, то надо взять ключ с сайта (строчка длинная) и заменить в ней  и  на твой пароль и юзера. Юзер это не логин от сайта, его нужно создать отдельно во вкладке Database access на сайте.

Comment: Слева подключения это подключения автора. При подключении к локальной базе с параметрами по умолчанию ошибка.

Comment: в поле где написано localhost надо ввести localhost от руки